# How to update file data in azure data lake

Tags: azure-data-lake

i uploaded a file in azure data lake.I want to upload same file again with updated data and want to update existing file. So what is the process?

Comment: Could you please describe your issue in detail? Overwriting or appending?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Lake store is not recommended for overwrite existing files(i.e. random writes).

**Note:** If you want to use the same filename and location, you can replace a file by overwriting it or delete the existing file and then upload.

[image]

Here are the steps how to upload file data in Azure data lake store:

Make sure to select "**Allow overwrite existing files**".

[image]